# Printing a file in python as a list gets printed as hex values, while printing them as lines they are separated with spaces and new lines

Tags: python, printing

adding

```
print(variable, end="", sep="")
```

didn't help

**here is my code that prints that file as a variable (as a list)**

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    variable = f.readlines()
print(variable)
```

here is the output

```
['?\u200f6\x00l\x001\x00a\x00d\x00l\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x006\x00k\x00t\x00i\x00q\x00e\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x006\x00k\x00t\x00j\x00j\x00d\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x006\x00k\x00t\x00l\x009\x00o\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x006\x00k\x00w\x007\x001\x000\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x006\x00k\x00x\x00o\x00s\x00f\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x005\x00m\x00w\x00n\x00h\x008\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x00']
```

here is the file contents

```
6l1adl
6ktiqe
6ktjjd
6ktl9o
6kw710
6kxosf
5mwnh8
```

**printing the file line by line**

```
for line in variable:
    print (line, end="", sep="")
```

here is the output

```
??6 l 1 a d l

 6 k t i q e

 6 k t j j d

 6 k t l 9 o

 6 k w 7 1 0

 6 k x o s f

 5 m w n h 8
```

**I also tried these**

```
lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

but I got same results

so I tried changing the file to utf8 and now printing gives me this

```
['ï»?6l1adl', '6ktiqe', '6ktjjd', '6ktl9o', '6kw710', '6kxosf', '5mwnh8']
```

very close but what's this `ï»?` in the beginning

so I was trying to fix it with slicing

```
variable[0] = (variable[0])[3:]
```

but I still want to know why this all happened

btw yes I do close the file in the end

I have been searching google and trying everything since yesterday so almost 12 hours and I couldn't fine an answer anywhere, so I had no other place than to ask here, if any more info is needed tell me

ps. while writing all this I kinda fixed the problem temporally but still I want an explanation

Comment: The `ï»?` in the beginning is the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and it'd look like your file is originally UTF-16 encoded. The hex values are the representation of the zero-bytes.

Comment: Judging from your use of print as a function, you're using Python 3, but could you confirm this? Also please include what [`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is for you.

Comment: this explains it, yes my file was saved in unicode mode and I changed it to utf8, but what are these "zero-bytes"? where did they come from? how do I fix the file so I don't have them?

Comment: You are opening your file in text mode, but with incorrect encoding, so it is misinterpreted. The original would seem like it is encoded as [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), so `with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-16') as f: ...`. In UTF-16 each unicode codepoint is encoded as a single 16bit codeunit that has same numerical value as the corresponding code point.

Comment: Yes I'm using Python 3.6, but sorry what's this `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`? I tried adding that `encoding='utf-16'` too but it produced an error

Comment: [Edit] your Question and add the `Traceback` Output.

Comment: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is what Python consults for an encoding, if opening a file in text mode and not providing an explicit encoding. Read the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) docs that I linked to in the previous comment mentioning it. Did you try opening the original file with the zero bytes, or your utf-8 version with the `ï»?` while providing `encoding='utf-16'`?